# Testng suite file is ignored when executing it from maven, because of which my listeners aren't being called

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I am trying to run my test through testng using maven, the tests and listeners execute fine when i directly run the the testng suite but when i try running it from maven the testng suite files are completely ignored. My test get executed as they have word test in them, but the listeners are not invoked.

I have tried all the possible solution present out there, but it just won't work. I have tried executing maven through cmd in the hopes that it might give some different results, but nothing helped.
The TestNg.xml file has been placed in the test\resources folder
I have tried placing the TestNg.xml in different locations.
I have tried using different jdk versions.
I have tried using different surefire versions.
I tried running it using "mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=TestNg.xml" still maven doesn't run as per the TestNg.xml suite file

Below is my pom.xml and TestNg.xml files.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nitesh</groupId>
    <artifactId>DataDrivenFramework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore -->
                    <!-- outputDirectory>src/target/surefire-reports/html</outputDirectory -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>TestNg.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!-- properties> <property> <name>usedefaultlisteners</name> <value>false</value> 
                        </property> <property> <name>listener</name> <value>com.nitesh.listeners.CustomListeners,org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value> 
                        </property> <property> <name>reporter</name> <value>listenReport.Reporter</value> 
                        </property> </properties -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.72</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <!--scope>test</scope -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

TestNg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="DataDriven">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.nitesh.listeners.CustomListeners" />
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="BankManagerLoginTestCases">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.nitesh.testcases.BankManagerLoginTestCase" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <!--  test name="CustomerAddTestCase">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.nitesh.testcases.CustomerAddTestCase" />
        </classes>
    </test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Unfortunately no answer.

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1- Add this in your plugins in pom**

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                        <value>false</value> <!-- disabling default listeners is optional -->
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>copperwire.io.listeners.TestAnnotationTransformerListener,copperwire.io.listeners.EmailExecutionListener</value>
                    </property>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <propertyName>upto_stage</propertyName>
                            <propertyName>order_id</propertyName>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <!-- <suiteFile>testng.xml</suiteFile> -->
                            <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                    <!-- <property> <name>reporter</name> <value>listenReport.Reporter</value> 
                        </property> -->
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin
```

> Blockquote

**STEP 2 - Run this via maven**

mvn clean test  -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml